# Android Unit tests broke when gradle was upgraded to 1.3.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I Recently I've switched to API 23; and upgraded gradle from 1.0.0 to 1.3.0.

So now I am not able to execute my android test cases. I end up with

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':App_Android:packageAppCrateDebugAndroidTest'.
```

> Unable to compute hash of /home/deeshank13/sl/App_Android/App/build/intermediates/classes-proguard/androidTest/AppCrate/debug/classes.jar

I do not have any warnings. I have fixed everything. Also the app is running fine yet test cases does not.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't upgrade the gradle plugin to the latest 1.5.0? And did you full clean before building?

Comment: what does `./gradlew --version` return?

Comment: @dtmilano it returns gradle 2.2.1

Comment: Try `./gradlew connectedCheck`

Comment: https://dl.dropbox.com/s/2p0or9ua7keq7il/OnPaste.20160223-162215.png?dl=0

Comment: you have to exclude some duplicate files

Comment: Add this to the android portion of your build.gradle file:
    
`packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
    exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'    }`

Comment: now i end up with new error https://dl.dropbox.com/s/ans4dip09bkur92/OnPaste.20160223-165701.png?dl=0